Solving $\cos(x)+\cos(7x)+\cos(5x)+\cos(3x)=0$
Here I have another problem from our Telegram group.
We are talking about fastest way of determining which of the following options gives the general solution to
$$\cos(x)+\cos(7x)+\cos(5x)+\cos(3x)=0$$

$\dfrac{n\pi}{4}$
$\dfrac{n\pi}{2}$
$\dfrac{n\pi}{8}$
none


Using the formula
$$\cos(A)+\cos(B)=2\cos\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)$$
into two pair, we got
\begin{align} 2\cos(4x)\cos(3x)+2\cos(4x)cos(x)&=0 \tag1\\
\cos(4x)\cos(2x)\cos(x)&=0 \tag2\\
x&=\frac{n\pi}{8}. \tag3
\end{align}
Is there any other idea so that I can solve this question?

I am new to math exchange i am using online sites to convert it, sometimes they work nicely and sometimes very bad at writing, thanks for correcting me

yes i have fixed the typo

The 3 first choices contain $\pi$ as a solution, but $\pi$ is not a solution. The answer is 4.

Recall that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\cos((2k-1)x) = \frac{\sin(2nx)}{2\sin(x)}$ for $\sin(x) \neq 0$. So your equation becomes $\sin(8x)=0$ for $x \neq m\pi,\, m \in \mathbb{Z}$. And if $ x= m\pi$ then $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\cos((2k-1)x)   =\sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{m} \neq 0 $.
The solution set is thus $\{\frac{\pi m}{8}\in \mathbb{R}:m \in \mathbb{Z}, \, 8 \text{ doesn't divide } m \}$.

this is awesome
